# Java object slicing confusion

Tags: java

I have a base and drive class(inheriting base class). And my based class is having object of drive class. So when I am invoking the overridden function it is giving me right result, by calling the drive class function as the based class is having drive class object.
But when i am just printing the variable present in both base and drive class (having same name) from based class object, it prints the value of the variable present in base class. Is there a way i can print drive class variable.

```
class A
{
    int i = 10;

    public void func(){
        System.out.print("print i :  " +i);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    int i = 20;
    public void func(){
        System.out.print("print i :  " +i);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();

        System.out.println(a.i);
        a.func();
    }
}
```

Output is:-

```
10
print i :  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 a.i
```

You are referencing the base class. Base class has "i" and you are referencing it, getting 10.

```
 a.func()
```

Second output gives 20 because function gets closest scope i which hides base class i.

Answer (score 0):

Each class has it's own instance of `i`. If you wanted `B` to inherit `i` from `A`, you need to remove `int i = 20` from `B`. If you want to initialize `i` when you construct a new `B`, do so in a constructor.

```
public B(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}
```

However, if you don't want to do that, and want to access `i` from the parent class, you can refer to it by saying `super.i`.

```
class B extends A
{
    int i = 20;
    public void func(){
        System.out.print("print i :  " + super.i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jeremy-heiler can you please help me understand little more.. When the Base class pointer is able to invoke drive class function then why it is not able to call variable ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: When the Base class is able to call drive class function then why it is not able to print drive class variable of same name ?

Comment: Consider reading the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e12172

Comment: Because `a.i` refers to the `i` from `A`, not `B`.

Comment: Instance methods that have the same signature as a supertype's method _override_ the supertype method. The use of overridden methods from pointers declared as the supertype is called _polymorphism_, and is one of the pillars of object-oriented (O-O) programming. This does not apply to variables, only methods. You cannot override an instance variable, you can only hide it. Look up "hiding member variables in Java" with your favorite search engine, and read the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method ("getter") and override it as well, or then you can access the superclass' variable using the keyword "super":

```
System.out.println(super.i);
```

Comment: Hi @Boschi I am looking to access drive class variable with base class pointer holding drive class object.

Comment: Since the variable names are the same, from the "MainClass" you will not have access to this variable unless you expose it somehow (a "getter" is the recommended OO approach).